# How to process input DStream by separating it on RDDs to print Kafka messages?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm creating spark streaming application and want to process each kafka message separately. For now, I want just to log message values to validate that everything works. But when I trying to print message values I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I have if condition to skip empty RDDs. The problem is with line `logger.warn(s"Message ${message.value.toString}")` because without it everything works fine. What can be the cause of the exception?

My idea is to split input `DStream` on separate RDDs so I am using `foreachRDD` method. Using it, I should get  RDDs of `ConsumerRecord` where the first element is key and second is the actual value. Then I am starting processing each `ConsumerRecord` trying to extract message value and print it.

```
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    streamingContext,
    PreferConsistent,
    Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
  )

kafkaStream.foreachRDD( (rdd: RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]], time: Time) =>
    if(!rdd.isEmpty){
      rdd.foreach(message =>
        if(!message.value().isEmpty){
          logger.warn(s"Message ${message.value.toString}")
        }else{
          logger.warn(s"Empty value")
        }
      )
    }else{
      logger.warn(s"Empty rdd")
    }
  )
```